# Update the mysql table row of column type JsonBlob

Tags: python, mysql, json

Consider the structure of table field 'extra' is as follows:

```
extra = sql.Column(sql.JsonBlob())
```

So it is of JsonBlob type.

Now I need to update some values in to the field 'extra'.

When I am trying to update the 'extra' value, it ends up in error which is as follows:

```
  File "basic_test.py", line 38
    sql = "update project set extra=('{"creation_date": "%s"}') where id=('%s')" % (date, tenant_id)
                                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Code I have tried is as follows:

```
    import datetime
    mylist = []
    today = datetime.date.today()
    mylist.append(today)
    date = mylist[0]

    tenant_id = '1578f81703ec4bbaa1d548532c922ab9'

    sql = "update project set extra='{"creation_date": "%s"}' where id=('%s')" % (date, tenant_id)
    cur.execute(sql)
```

**Note:**

For example, I am providing here the same type of data used in another table.

I have selected the rows from the table and providing the sample here.

```
('{"email": "test@example.com"}',)
<type 'tuple'>
```

So this is the type of data which is being stored in extra field.

Some one have a look and let me know your comments.

Let me know If it needs more Information.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself.

```
extra = '{"creation_date": "%s"}' % date

sql = "update project set extra=('%s') where id=('%s')" % (extra, tenant_id)
```

Changed the query as above so that I can be able to see that DB table is getting updated as needed correctly.